# javascript and jquery not working on mobile and site stops loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, responsive

I have designed a site using php as backend and javascript jquery as front end . The site works fine on PC but on mobile nothing works, the site stops loading after 2-3 seconds of initial loading and the animations , effects stops working. There is one error on console, i am not sure what it does

```
bad element for masonry: null
```

The site is responsive, works fine on mobile tester extension for browser . Can anybody help me out. I will provide the code for the script giving the error

link : https://codeshare.io/VSGJx

line no 703 is giving the error

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I will provide the code for the script giving the error"* - Yes, please [edit] your question to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @nnnnnn pasted....